# CRM 2011 Custom page and SQL TimeZone Issue

Tags: t-sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a custom aspx application that directly queries the CRM database base tables such as ActivityPointer to get the data such as due date, created on etc. The custom aspx page need to filter data based on certain date range such as for today, last 7 days etc. It does so by executing custom sproc stored in CRM database. However I am facing challenge with the user timezone issue getting the correct data.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @NoOfDay INT= 7 -- passed as param
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, @NoOfDays-1, GETDATE()), 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, - 1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

This will always return the startdate and enddate based on the machine timezone where the sql instance is running. What would be the correct approach to set the start date/end date so it also considers user timezone settings? I don't think I can use CRM specific functions such as dbo.fn_UTCToLocalTime() etc because my custom aspx will be using a different account to access/execute the sproc.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from maybe a direct SQL call being a little overkill for this, I'd just change the SP to accept a start and end date, and send in the UTC version of the dates you want to constrain the results to

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be hitting the tables directly. CRM provides a whole bunch of views that add additional fields (and cater for security roles etc).

If you look at the Views, you should find FilteredActivityPointer. This view will then have the date-time formatted and time-zone adjusted based on your current user.

The Filtered* views should be used for all reports